# Как сделать сайдбар по всей высоте родителя?

Tags: css, bootstrap, height

Как сделать блок "[Соседние статьи](https://mine.by/wiki/cmds)" справа по всей высоте родительского блока?
Раньше у родительского блока была задана `height`, но ее пришлось переделать в `min-height` из-за поломки верстки при использовании аккордиона.

Или может быть как-то можно пофиксить работу самого аккордиона при `height: 100%` (вместо `min-height`)?

Answer (score 0):

Сверстать по-современному.

```
.content {display:flex;}
.sidebar, .article {height:auto;}
```

чтобы сайдбар был справа, или поместить его в коде после .arcticle, или задать ему flex-order больше чем у .article (> 0), или задать flex-order самому .article:

```
.article {
  order: -1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Ну и, конечно, выкинуть все лишние элементы.